# Calculating a common height for nodes with different amounts of text in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When using labelled nodes (e.g. for a flow chart), their sizes are automatically chosen. One can enforce the same size, which must be known a priori, for multiple nodes by using "large enough" values for `minimum height` and `minimum width`.

In the following example the node width is restricted for spacial reasons. This leads to the boxes containing different numbers of lines and therefore different box sizes.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node[rectangle,text width=5em,draw=black] (leftnode) {Short text};
        \node[rectangle,text width=5em,draw=black,right=of leftnode] (rightnode) {A text longer than the other one};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Given two strings, that shall be written in two separate nodes of equal size: Is it possible to let LaTeX calculate the minimal node height that is large enough for both cases and use it as a parameter for the nodes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Identical Heights:

When you specify the `text width`, the text is placed in a `\parbox` of the width provided by `text width`.  So, a simple fix is to use a `\vphantom{}` in the shorter node to ensure that it is of the same height:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand*{\TextWidth}{5em}%
\newcommand*{\StringA}{Short}%
\newcommand*{\StringB}{A text longer than the other one}%

\newcommand{\VPhantom}{\vphantom{\parbox{\TextWidth}{\StringB}}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.1cm]
    \node[rectangle,text width=\TextWidth,draw=black, red] (leftnode) {\VPhantom\StringA};
    \node[rectangle,text width=\TextWidth,draw=black, blue, right=of leftnode] (rightnode) {\StringB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Identical Widths

You can use the `\widthof{}` to compute the length and then chose the maximum width as the `minimum length`:

[image]

### Note

- The `2*\InnerSep` adjusts for the value of `inner sep` that is on both sides of the node, so if that value is changed this formula will need to be adjusted as well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\InnerSep}{0.333em}%
\newcommand*{\StringA}{short}%
\newcommand*{\StringB}{a longer string}%

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\MinimumWidth}{%
    max(\widthof{\StringA},\widthof{\StringB})+2*\InnerSep%
}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum width=\MinimumWidth]
    \node [rectangle, draw=red]  at (0,0) {\StringA};
    \node [rectangle, draw=blue] at (0,1) {\StringB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Turns out, I have not been specific enough.
From the idea this is exactly, what I am looking for, but I want to control the height as well.
Using `\heightof` alone does not do the trick, because the macro may not contain `\\`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tim: I am not sure what you mean by "may not contain a `\\`. Best if you update the question and compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the exact problem.

Comment: What I meant was newline `\\`, which gives an error when it is used inside your example.

I changed the question now.

Comment: Have updated the solution to provide the same height nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works well if the smaller string only uses one line. For multiple lines in both nodes I came to the following solution (combining both approaches given above and using the `calc` package).

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \newcommand*{\TextWidth}{5em}
    \newcommand*{\Innersep}{0.33em}
    \newcommand{\StringA}{Short multiline text}
    \newcommand{\StringB}{A text longer than the other one}
    \newlength\myheight
    \setlength{\myheight}{\totalheightof{\parbox{\TextWidth}{\StringB}}+Innersep*2}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node[rectangle,text width=\TextWidth,inner sep=\Innersep,minimum height=\myheight,draw=black] (leftnode) {\StringA};
        \node[rectangle,text width=\TextWidth,inner sep=\Innersep,minimum height=\myheight,draw=black,right=of leftnode] (rightnode) {\StringB};
    \end{tikzpicture}     
    \end{frame}     
    \end{document}
```