# What is the way to left-align labels in a tikz-timing diagram?

Tags: tikz-timing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\newcommand{\degr}{degr}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock 128\,MHz 0\degr    & H   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  \color{red}\tiny Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C \\ % starts with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 180\degr  & C   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 270\degr  &     12{2C} C \\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

I'd like all labels 'Clock...' to be left aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The nodes used for those captions use the style `/tikz/timing/name`.

You can append to this style options like

- `align=left` and
- `text width=1.4in` (to use the example of [Stefen B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes)’ [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125724/16595)).

Of course, if you don’t want to guess the width of the widest box you can either set `text width=\widthof{<longest text>}` or use the idea behind [Dependent node size in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227/16595) for the a most automatic solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\newcommand{\degr}{degr}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/name/.append style={align=left, text width=1.4in}]
  Clock 128\,MHz 0\degr    & H   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  \color{red}\tiny Clock 128\,MHz 90\degr   & [C] 12{2C} C \\ % starts with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 180\degr  & C   12{2C} G \\ % ends with edge
  Clock 128\,MHz 270\degr  &     12{2C} C \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: With my [`node-families`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex) library, it is also possible to say `timing/name/.append style={Text Width=timing, align=left}` after all rows has been added to `tikztimingtable` environment. (The implementation of `Text Width` is not perfect.)