# Using \phantom in subscript with the bayesnet TikZ library

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, subscripts

I'm using the `bayesnet` TikZ library to draw a graphical model. Node variables might have different size, say `$v_0$` and `$v_{N-1}$` and the result is that some bubbles are bigger than others. I am trying to use `\phantom` to create bubbles of the same size like this:

```
\node[obs] (v0) {$v_{0\phantom{N-}}$};
```

The problem with this solution is that the label is pushed all the way to the left inside the bubble. Referring to the above fragment, is there a way to compute the space taken by `{N-}` (note that it's a subscript) and distribute it evenly to the left and right of `$v_0$`?

Comment: Sure there is, `\sbox0{$\scriptstyle N-$}` and then you can use `\hspace{.5\wd0}` on both ends. But why don’t you use the `minimum width` key to esnure a certain width for all nodes (bubbles). Or even something like [Dependent node size in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227)?

Comment: I had not realized that I could pass the `minimum width` key. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can measure the width. With

```
\sbox0{$\scriptstyle N-$}
```

and one

```
\hspace*{.5\wd0}
```

before and after the actual content would solve this.

But it is easier to use the `text width` key (or `minimum width` subtracting the `/pgf/inner xsep` values). You can use either `\widthof` (more robust) or PGFmath’s `width` function.

Furthermore you can also simply specify any arbitrary value for `minimum width` or `text width`.

And if you do not want to give the content before hand you can use the `.aux` file as in [Dependent node size in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
\node           {$v_{N-1}$};
\node at (0,-.5) {$v_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,align=center,text width=\widthof{$v_{N-1}$}}]
\node           {$v_{N-1}$};
\node at (0,-.5) {$v_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,align=center,text width=width("$v_{N-1}$")}]
\node           {$v_{N-1}$};
\node at (0,-.5) {$v_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,minimum width=+3.5em}]
\node           {$v_{N-1}$};
\node at (0,-.5) {$v_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
\node           {$v_{N-1}$};
\node at (0,-.5) {\sbox0{$\scriptstyle N-$}\hspace*{.5\wd0}$v_0$\hspace*{.5\wd0}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Original

[image]

#### `\widthof{…}`

[image]

#### `width("…")`

[image]

#### Arbitrary value

[image]

#### Measuring

[image]