# How to force nodes to have the same size in tikz matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, matrices, tikz-matrix

Is there some intelligent way to have several tikz nodes have the same height and width?  Consider the following example with output below.

I'd like every node in each row to have the same height equal to the height of the tallest node and every node in each column to have the same width equal to the width of the widest node.

In the example below each node in the third row has a different height.  In the first two rows the heights are forced to be equal using \vphantom.  There must be a more intelligent way to do this.  Any ideas?  What about the columns (they contain identical nodes, but they would not normally)?

I don't want to hard-code a minimum width+height.

Thank you!

J.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={anchor=base}]
\matrix [draw=red]
{
\node[fill=Orange] {a\vphantom{Xg}}; & \node[fill=Green] {X\vphantom{ag}}; & \node[fill=LightGreen] {\vphantom{aX}g}; \\
\node[fill=Yellow] {a\vphantom{Xg}}; & \node[fill=Cyan] {X\vphantom{ag}}; & \node[fill=Magenta] {\vphantom{aX}g}; \\
\node[fill=Purple] {a}; & \node[fill=LightBlue] {X}; & \node[fill=Aquamarine] {g}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Recommended reading http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what I want, but it's admittedly not pretty.  It's motivated by [Dependent node size in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107227/dependent-node-size-in-tikz) .

I'm puzzled why using

```
column 1/.style={Minimum Width=c1}
```

etcetera doesn't work the same way as the row style commands.  Thanks all.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,node-families,matrix}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}, 
row 1/.style={Minimum Height=r1,Text Height=th1,Text Depth=td1},
row 2/.style={Minimum Height=r2,Text Height=th2,Text Depth=td2},
row 3/.style={Minimum Height=r3,Text Height=th3,Text Depth=td3}
]
\matrix [matrix of nodes,draw=Red,nodes in empty cells]
{
|[fill=Orange,Minimum Width=col1]| a & |[fill=Green,Minimum Width=col2]| X & |[fill=LightGreen,Minimum Width=col3]| \\
|[fill=Yellow,Minimum Width=col1]| a & |[fill=Cyan,Minimum Width=col2]| & |[fill=Magenta,Minimum Width=col3]| g \\
|[fill=Purple,Minimum Width=col1]| & |[fill=LightBlue,Minimum Width=col2]| X & |[fill=Aquamarine,Minimum Width=col3]| \tikz\draw[fill=Black]  (0,0) circle(1cm); \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled, too, but you can do `column 1/.style={nodes={Minimum Width=col1}}` and so on.

Answer (score 20):

Using `text depth` and `text height`, you can control the total height for the nodes; `text width` gives you control over the width (there's also a `minimum size` key which could be used):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,text width=1em}]
\matrix [draw=red]
{
\node[fill=Orange] {a}; & \node[fill=Green] {X}; & \node[fill=LightGreen] {g}; \\
\node[fill=Yellow] {a}; & \node[fill=Cyan] {X}; & \node[fill=Magenta] {g}; \\
\node[fill=Purple] {a}; & \node[fill=LightBlue] {X}; & \node[fill=Aquamarine] {g}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **percusse** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191239/how-to-force-nodes-to-have-the-same-size-in-tikz-matrices#comment440989_191240), a `matrix of nodes` (requires the `matrix` library) could be more useful here; it simplifies the code and also gives you a `nodes in empty cells` key to deal with the case of cells without explicit text:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,text width=1em}]
\matrix [matrix of nodes,draw=red,nodes in empty cells]
{
|[fill=Orange]| a & |[fill=Green]| X & |[fill=LightGreen]| \\
|[fill=Yellow]| a & |[fill=Cyan]| & |[fill=Magenta]| g \\
|[fill=Purple]| & |[fill=LightBlue]| X & |[fill=Aquamarine]| g \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this begs for `matrix of nodes` for reduced input

Comment: @percusse You're right. I added a remark to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but (as mentioned in the question) I don't want to hard-code the width and height. I want it to be automatically determined and set equal to the maximum sizes in each row and column.  (And the nodes need not contain text.)

Comment: @JPi For nodes without text, there's a `nodes in empty cells` key in a `matrix of nodes`. For the other part, this could perhaps be done, but I'm not sure it it's worth the effort.

Comment: It is worth the effort for me (but thanks!).  (I meant it could contain an object other than text.)

Comment: @JPi I'll leave my answer in case is useful for someone else; in the edit I illustrate the use of the `nodes in empty cells` key to deal with the case of cells without text.

Comment: @JPi if you now the widest/highest/deepest entry, then you can easily measure its dimensions and then use those values to set text width/height/depth.

Comment: Thank you.  I voted up, but am hopeful someone will answer the more complicated question.

Comment: Yes, I could use the settobox package or something like that.

Comment: @JPi What you want is only possible after reading the matrix completely first and going back and rendering the matrix again. TikZ doesn't do such things yet such as `align` or `tabular` do.