# Not able to align nodes properly

Tags: tikz-matrix

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=2cm,color=gray] (-4.001,-6.001) grid (6,4);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,inner sep=1cm, nodes={align=center}]{
A & B & C & D & E \\
A & B & C & D & E \\
A & B & C & D & E \\
A & B & C & D & E \\
A & B & C & D & E \\};

\foreach \y in {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2}
    \draw ($(-5, 2*\y)$) -- ($(-5, 2*\y)$) node {$\y$};
\foreach \x in {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}
    \draw ($(2*\x, 5)$) -- ($(2*\x, 5)$) node {$\x$};


\foreach \x in {-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6} {
  \foreach \y in {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4}  {
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (\x,\y) {};
   }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

And I am trying to align the matrix such that each element of 0, A, B, ..., E is in the center of a square, but I am not able to get this to work. I don't understand why 'column sep' shifts the terms more and more.

Thanks!

Comment: `column sep={2cm,between origins}`? Isn't `($(-3, \y) + (-2, \y)$)` just `(-5, 2*\y)`? Can you complete your example to a full MWE and show what you want to achieve? I’d use only `matrix` for this, though.

Comment: Hi Qrrbrbirlbel! I've updated my post with a MWE. When you run the code you will get a grid. I want the elements in the matrix to be aligned such that each element is in it's respective square. So the top most-left square should have an 'A' and the bottom most-right square should contain an 'E'. I also want these elements to be centered in the square.

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191239/how-to-force-nodes-to-have-the-same-size-in-tikz-matrices/191285#191285

Comment: Thanks! I added `every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=-1cm,text height=1cm,text width=0cm}` in `\matrix[{INSERT HERE}]` and it seems to be working. After further investigation it seems like what I needed was `text width=0cm` (and also height)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it completely with a matrix. If you set the nodes to

```
draw=gray, minimum size=+1cm, outer sep=+0pt, text depth=+-.5ex, text height=+1ex
```

you get a grid-like set of boxes. The `column sep` and `row sep` needs to bet set to `-\pgflinewidth` so that the nodes overlap.

The dots can then be added via two `\foreach` loops:

```
\foreach \row in {1,...,4}{
  \foreach \column in {1,...,6}
    \node at (m-\row-\column.north west) [dot]
     [if={\row==4}{insert path=node at (m-\row-\column.south west) [dot]}{}];
  \node at (m-\row-6.north east)[dot];
}
\node at (m-4-6.south east)[dot];
```

(This only adds one dot at each corner. Simpler loops can be constructed, they however add multiple dots at most corners.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={fill,circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt, node contents=},
]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={draw=gray, minimum size=+1cm, outer sep=+0pt,
  text depth=+-.5ex, text height=1ex}
  ] (m) {
0 & A & B & C & D & E \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
};
\foreach \row in {1,...,4}{
  \foreach \column in {1,...,6}
    \node at (m-\row-\column.north west) [dot]
     [if={\row==4}{insert path=node at (m-\row-\column.south west) [dot]}{}];
  \node at (m-\row-6.north east)[dot];
}
\node at (m-4-6.south east)[dot];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you are feeling more adventurous, you can add these dots as part of labels of the matrix’s nodes. This needs, however, two fixes:

- An override of the automatically selected anchor for the labels,
  see [How can I set the TikZ label anchor explicitly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106791/16595)
- As labels are nodes themselved, they also get the `every node` style applied. If we add those dots as labels to the `every node` style we would get an infinite amount of recursion. (Every label would get labels which get labels …)

  For this I introduce the `not if label` key which argument will only get applied if the node it is used in is not a label. (For a `pin` a similar key can be constructed.)

Unfortunately, the labels will count to a cell’s dimension, so you will either need to accommodate their sizes into the `column sep` and `row sep` or add `overlay` to the `dot` style. This might make them protrude outside of the picture if the `inner sep`s of the matrix is smaller than half the size of the dots.

Again, the addition of the dots is done so that every dot is only drawn once.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{not if label/.code={%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{tikz@save@last@fig@name}{\pgfkeysalso{#1}}{}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  label anchor/.style={tikz@label@post/.append style={anchor=#1}},
  label dots/.style={label={[dot,label anchor=center]#1:}},
  nw dots/.style={label dots=north west},
  sw dots/.style={label dots=south west},
  ne dots/.style={label dots=north east},
  se dots/.style={label dots=south east}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={fill,circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt, overlay},
]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={not if label={
    nw dots, draw=gray, minimum size=+1cm,
    outer sep=+0pt, text depth=+-.5ex, text height=1ex}},
  column 6/.style      ={nodes={not if label=ne dots}},
  row 4/.style         ={nodes={not if label=sw dots}},
  row 4 column 6/.style={nodes={not if label=se dots}},
  ]{
0 & A & B & C & D & E \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]