# Cannot get rid of a double horizontal line in Tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, line

I hope someone can help me with my problem. I have created a matrix using Tikz as I have to be able to cross out columns and rows, however, I cannot get rid of a double horizontal line LaTeX inserts in between the second and third row (but NOT in the first column) and I cannot see where it comes from. Except from that double line, the matrix is exactly the way I want it to be.

This is my code at the moment for the matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \matrix (magic) [%
   matrix of nodes,
   nodes=draw,
   text width=6mm,
   text  centered,
   column 1/.style={
    nodes={
        text width=20mm,
        minimum width=20mm,
        fill=white
    }
},
 ] {%
     & (dd) & (cd) & (dc) & (cc) \\
   cooperate & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
   defect & 1 & 6 & 1 & 6\\
 };

 \draw[thin,red] (magic-2-1.west) -- (magic-2-5.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191240/31034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tikz matrix` is not a tabular, all `nodes` keep their size and the `matrix` just aligns them. In this case, `cooperate` nodes is higher than other nodes in its row. That's the reason for the double line. Lines are node's border not a (tabular) `\hline`. One solution consist in fixing a `minimum height` which forces all nodes to have similar size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \matrix (magic) [%
   matrix of nodes,
   nodes={anchor=center, draw, minimum height=8mm},
   text width=6mm,
   text  centered,
   column 1/.style={
    nodes={
        text width=20mm,
        minimum width=20mm,
        fill=white
    }
},
 ] {%
     & (dd) & (cd) & (dc) & (cc) \\
   cooperate & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
   defect & 1 & 6 & 1 & 6\\
 };

 \draw[thin,red] (magic-2-1.west) -- (magic-2-5.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that all lines show same width, insert `row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth` in matrix options.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ferahfeza, adding `text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex` aligns your texts and solves your problem.

Ignasi arrived first, however, as he said, I've added `row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth` to avoid thick lines.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document} 
    \centering 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex] 
    \matrix (magic) [% 
        matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, text width=6mm, text centered,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column 1/.style={ 
            nodes={ 
                text width=20mm, minimum width=20mm, fill=white 
                } 
            }, 
        ] {% 
            & (dd) & (cd) & (dc) & (cc) \\ 
            cooperate & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\ 
            defect & 1 & 6 & 1 & 6\\ 
        }; 
    \draw[thin,red] (magic-2-1.west) -- (magic-2-5.east); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Inge You're welcome! Indeed, it's much better!