# Tikz: align baseline of multiple labels below nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-positioning

I need some help with tikz. I have multiple nodes with labels and my problem is that the labels that are below a node are placed in such a way that their upper boundaries align. How can i change it such that the labels align at their baseline? Here a minimal example, the labels above the nodes look fine but the ones below are horrible.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,label=above:$n$] at (0,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:$n$] at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:$n-1$] at (1,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:$n-1$] at (1,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:$c$] at (2,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:$c$] at (2,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:$d$] at (3,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:$d$] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Add `\vphantom{d1-}` (or `\strut` or `\mathstrut`) too all or set a fixed `text height` for all, `text height={height("$d1-$"})` to mimic the `\vphantom` solution. See also [Q107227](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227) and related question. TikZ packs all text relatively tightly and uses the border of the text to place it. You will need to have all nodes the same vertical dimension to have them align properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick hack to make all the labels the same height:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill,label=above:\strut$n$] at (0,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:\strut$n$] at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:\strut$n-1$] at (1,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:\strut$n-1$] at (1,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:\strut$c$] at (2,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:\strut$c$] at (2,0) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=above:\strut$d$] at (3,1) {};
\node[circle,fill,label=below:\strut$d$] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the same as the solution by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz (+1), but for convenience you can make a style that adds a `\strut` to each label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, fill, label=#1\strut}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode=above:$n$] at (0,1) {};
\node[mynode=below:$n$] at (0,0) {};
\node[mynode=above:$n-1$] at (1,1) {};
\node[mynode=below:$n-1$] at (1,0) {};
\node[mynode=above:$c$] at (2,1) {};
\node[mynode=below:$c$] at (2,0) {};
\node[mynode=above:$d$] at (3,1) {};
\node[mynode=below:$d$] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer without using label of nodes. From [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/strut.htm)

> \strut - Used to create an invisible box with no width, height 8.6pt and depth 3pt.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill=brown,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\path
(0,1) node[c]{} node[above]{\strut$n$} 
(1,1) node[c]{} node[above]{\strut$n-1$}
(2,1) node[c]{} node[above]{\strut$c$}
(3,1) node[c]{} node[above]{\strut$g$}
;
\path
(0,0) node[c]{} node[below]{\strut$n$} 
(1,0) node[c]{} node[below]{\strut$n-1$}
(2,0) node[c]{} node[below]{\strut$h$}
(3,0) node[c]{} node[below]{\strut$y$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```